# Inverse Image Mapping with Corner Detection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to identify playing cards in images. After I have successfully detected edges using Canny ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/79x8K.jpg ), I know that I must use the inverse perspective transform to map the playing card for a straight look so that I can use template matching to identify the card. Is corner detection a viable method to engineering the inverse perspective of a single, or multiple, card? And if so, what would be a good corner detection -> inverse perspective transform technique combination to employ?

For the record I'm trying to implement this in my own code, as apposed to relying heavily on OpenCV, but any guidance to achieving this goal would be appreciated.

Comment: imho you can identify all cards by analyzing contours without perspective transformation. if you share your code to get given image i can show you something to improve my idea ( i want to see your code to understand if i could help you, because my idea depends on using OpenCV c++ )

Comment: I can put my code up a little later on, but feel free to share your idea. I can successfully detect the edges, but after that I'm lost. What would be your idea using OpenCV? Even if I just outline the process with OpenCV functions I can develop my own code later. I'll get the code up when I'm home. How would you approach it from the stage following Canny onward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not a complate answer,just to show my idea this simple code helps to understand how contours can be filtered to analyze easily.

i think implementing a simple identifier (for pictureless cards) is possible by counting of countours that inside the card's contour. (sorry for my poor english)

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int, char** argv )
{
    Mat src,src_gray;
    src = imread(argv[1]);
    if (src.empty())
    {
        cerr << "No image supplied ..." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    src_gray = src_gray <127;

    // to simplicify contours
    dilate(src_gray,src_gray,Mat(),Point(-1,-1),2);
    erode(src_gray,src_gray,Mat(),Point(-1,-1),10);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<Point> approx;

    findContours( src_gray, contours, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    src = Scalar(255,255,255);

    int counter = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        approxPolyDP(contours[i],approx,15,true);

        Scalar color;

        if( approx.size() == 4 & contourArea(approx) > 5000 )
            color = Scalar(0,0,255);

        {
            drawContours(src,contours,i,Scalar(0,255,0),1, LINE_AA, hierarchy, 1);
            polylines(src,approx,true,color);
            if( approx.size() == 3 ) counter++;
        }
    }
    putText(src, format("%d",counter), Point(100, 100),FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, Scalar(255,0,0), 4);
    imshow( "result", src );

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

result images :

[image]

[image]

**EDIT: code is updated**

Comment: So is there a way to detect corners like this? And what is the way to isolate particular cards, e.g. if there are multiple cards how do I know which contours represent which cards looking at the vectors, or which contours actually represent cards and not the different symbols? Do you filter by size of the contours? Thank you for your help!

Comment: So is there a way to detect corners like this? as you see the red rectangle is drawn with 4 corner points. the black coloured contours have the information of in which contour they are

Comment: I have it working in my own code, but just to clarify... ApproxPolyDP finds corners given contours? So find contours perform's it's name, and then I think if what you're checking for has 4 corners and is larger than a certain pixel threshold then you've determined it's a card?

Comment: yes exactly.you can try ApproxPolyDP with changed parameter values. as i stated my code is only a start point. if you share your code i can help more. to filter contours also you can use angles as you can see [squares.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp)

Comment: i think perspective correction is not necessary  but take a look at [this tutorial](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/)

Comment: To be honest my code is a bunch of functioning pre-processing stuff (Gaussian filter, contrast correction, thresholding) and then applying Canny with OpenCV. Aside from that I just converted your code to Java and it's all working, I was just trying to make sure I knew exactly what I was doing with the code you provided. That tutorial and your code has been extremely helpful, I'll try go from here but I'll show you some code if I have trouble in the coming days! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Let me say your pre-processing is very good.i am ready with all to help about this subject

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again, I got it all working with OpenCV and am having a new battle with writing my own Canny and Corner detection in Java! Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome. i wonder why you need to write your own canny and corner detection?

Comment: Just something I'm trying to do. It'd be very, very simple if I were to only use OpenCV, especially now I know the precise order of how to do things thanks to you, so writing my own source code for things is a bit more of a challenge. I may be giving up on that though, my own Canny isn't functioning. Hysteresis is not fun.

Comment: i updated the code. could you try with different cards

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant writing my own Canny Edge Detection in Java (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984650/tracking-weak-points-with-canny-edge-detection). Using your code I was able to locate and identify cards in the image! Didn't have any problem once I located the corners thanks to you.

Comment: How do you identify cards?

Comment: With the corner points I can get the transformation matrix to make the card the whole frame, use that to create a new image with standard height and width, use templates of space, club, diamond, heart, ace, two, etc... And use OpenCV's template matching, normalised cross correlation I think. Whatever produces the highest value is the suit, then I do the same for the rank.

Comment: I have no experience with template matching.i would like to be seen your code.

Comment: I can put it up tomorrow some time if you like, I'll just upload my template matching class in the post if you like?

Comment: github is good for sharing code (for example [look at my github page](https://github.com/sturkmen72) ). you can share what you want.