# Tracking Weak Points with Canny Edge Detection

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement my own version of Canny Edge Detection in Java, but I'm falling at the final hurdle. I can't follow the strong edges and detect weak points to solidify my edges. I've got some examples here:

Result of my Canny program:

[image]

Result of OpenCV's Canny Function:

[image]

And the starting image:

[image]

The following is the code I'm using to try and strengthen the edges:

```
    //main program
    for(int x = 1; x < width-1; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 1; y < height-1; y++)
        {
            if(src.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, tmp)[0] >= 250)
            {
                trackWeakOnes(x, y, src);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void trackWeakOnes(int x, int y, BufferedImage src) 
    {
        for (int a = x - 1; a <= x + 1; a++)
        {
            for (int b = y - 1; b <= y + 1; b++) 
            {
                if (checkWeak(a, b, src)) 
                {
                    src.getRaster().setPixel(x, y, tmpMax);
                    trackWeakOnes(a, b, src);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkWeak(int x, int y, BufferedImage src)
    {   
        return ((src.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, tmpPix)[0] > 0) && 
                (src.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, tmpPix)[0] < 255));
    }
```

tmpPix is an empty array to be filled, tmpMax is an array {255, 255, 255} to make edges white. I can add more code if anyone would like. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Edit: full source code -> http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3506

Edit 2: Result of LIRE source (still some broken edges around the card):

[image]

Comment: The hysteresis in the canny edge detector is basically starting from the non-weak and marking all connected weak as non-weak, or the other way around, you check for each weak pixel if it is connected to a strong one. If not, you delete it. Your approach does look sound to me, but maybe your thresholds are too high to achieve the very same image as with openCV. Have you checked if you use the same blur filter parameters and the same high and low threshold?

Comment: I'm using an image that is only black or white, so how much should the thresholds affect it? All values are 0 or 255. Given how broken the bottom and top edges are, could it be they're too far away for hysteresis to work? I have been using 5x5 Gaussian Blur filter after Grayscale and then thresholding the image. The OpenCV documentation shows you must apply Gaussian prior also, if that is what you meant by blur filter. I am using the same Matrix as they did. I'm almost certain the issue is my hysteresis, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, given hysteresis sets those below low threshold to be dark and sets those above the low threshold and below the high threshold to be an edge if it is connected to an edge, I may face trouble given that my values are 0 or 255 and will therefore always be below the thresholds unless they're detected as an edge from the beginning? I'm not sure how OpenCV succeeded, but it seems for a black and white image hysteresis would be ineffective?

Comment: I added my full source code if that is more helpful :)

Comment: With the setPixel method you distinguish between low and high .. I'd set low from 220 to something like 50. I checked your source against the one from LIRE (https://github.com/dermotte/LIRE/blob/ec70cc7f211bbac21bfaabb3bdebe94ff634bc8b/src/main/java/net/semanticmetadata/lire/imageanalysis/filters/CannyEdgeDetector.java), which looks extremely similar to me in approach, and it actually works there ;)

Comment: Yup I was using that as a guide... I've just completely copied the code into my project, but even that code doesn't seem to work! Is there a way to do a second round of hysteresis that will further strengthen lines? I'll add my result, but even the LIRE detection code doesn't fully detect the edges of the card, and that makes it useless later when I'm searching for contour with four corners. The resulting image of LIRE is at the end of my original question.

Comment: if they are not connected to a strong point, a second round of hysteresis will not help, maybe use less blur? I know that some algorithms like PHOG leave out the blur entirely.

Comment: Can't say it changed much. When I'm processing the image prior to Canny I blur, grayscale and then threshold. Do I need additional blurring after thresholding? Also what is PHOG? I'm pretty happy to try anything that will give me the same as that OpenCV image.